# MYSQL query with group function

Tags: mysql, database

I want to reach max value of a serie but this value must less than my current value.

For example this is my serie;

```
34 45 78 96 *114* 567
```

and `114` is my current value. How can I reach to 96?

I tried below query but it is giving error `Invalid use of group function`

```
SELECT ph_id FROM `photos` WHERE max(ph_id)<114 GROUP BY ph_id;
```

If it works I will replace 114 with a variable

Comment: You need to apply the MAX function on the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(ph_id) FROM `photos` WHERE ph_id < 114 GROUP BY ph_id;
```

Comment: please remove max() from WHERE clause. If you do it will work:)

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the HAVING clause for any aggregate functions:

```
SELECT MAX(ph_id) FROM `photos` HAVING max(ph_id)<114 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(ph_id) from photos where ph_id<114 group by ph_id ;
```